# Erro ao salvar caminho da imagem SQLITE: table .. has no column named

Tags: java, android, sqlite, imagem, netbeans

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está dando erro na hora de salvar o caminho da imagem no SQLITE. Diz que não tem uma coluna nomeada pathImagem na tabela produtos  Em anexo a imagem com o erro para melhor entendimento.

Minha Classe Produto Dao:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Produto;
import br.gestaoBd.Login;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProdutoDao {

public void inserirProduto(Produto produto) {
    System.out.println("Inserindo produto...");
    ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
    v.put("descricao", produto.getDescricao());
    v.put("precoDeCusto", produto.getPrecoDeCusto());
    v.put("percDeLucro", produto.getPercDeLucro());
    v.put("precoDeVenda", produto.getPrecoDeVenda());
    v.put("pathImagem", produto.getPathImagem());


    Login.db.insert("produtos", null, v);
    //ProjetoBd.db.close();
    System.out.println("Inseriu...");
}

public static void alterar(Produto produto) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("descricao", produto.getDescricao());
    cv.put("precoDeCusto", produto.getPrecoDeCusto());
    cv.put("percDeLucro", produto.getPercDeLucro());
    cv.put("precoDeVenda", produto.getPrecoDeVenda());
    cv.put("pathImagem", produto.getPathImagem());

 .........
```

Estrutura do banco

```
     ........

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [produtos] (");
    sb.append(" [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,");
    sb.append(" [descricao] VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [precoDeCusto] DOUBLE NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [percDeLucro] DOUBLE NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [precoDeVenda] DOUBLE NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [pathImagem] VARCHAR2(125) NOT NULL)"); 

     .........
```

Comment: A imagem corte a parte mais importante do erro. Coloque ele como texto mesmo. Só o cabeçalho basta. Parece estar tudo em ordem, mas o `INSERT` está um pouco estranho, não sei se é algo do ORM do Android. Já tentou listar a estrutura do banco para ter certeza que a coluna está lá?

Comment: @ bigown ERROR: SQLiteDatabase android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table produtos has no column named pathImagem (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO produtos(percDeLucro,descricao,pathImagem,precoDeVenda,precoDeCusto) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: Cheque a criação do banco de dados, se as colunas estão sendo criadas corretamente.

Comment: Já fiz isso.. até onde vi estão criadas corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalei a aplicação e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Não use a área de respostas para agradecer ou comentar, use antes a área de comentários. A área de respostas deve ser usada apenas para responder à pergunta.